# Unity gameobject turns black while adding point light

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, lighting

hello guys i have problem, while i set the value of exposure to zero then as usual everything turns black but then i added the point light and all the gameobjects works fine but the table turns black and i used the Lit shadergraph. Now when i change from opaque to transparent then it doesn't works in this point light but when i change it back to opaque in shader graph it works fine also in point light but i need the table glass to be alpha therefore i used alpha in shader graph.

before and after transparent in shader graph images and changing the exposure of skybox to 1 are given below and before and after changing.

Shader Graph:

[image: Shader Graph]

Table Before:

[image: Table Before]

Table after:

[image: Table after]

SkyBox after:

[image: SkyBox after]

SkyBox before:

[image: SkyBox before]